# Connect to Docker on a different machine on a Windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers

[Related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092669/running-docker-and-android-emulator-on-a-guest-virtual-machine) but not an (exactly) similar question, how do you run Docker on Windows but the "actual" Docker runs on a different machine.

So it's like, you have a Windows 10 guest VM machine as a development environment with Docker on it, but since it's a guest VM and nested virtualization is still in question, the actual docker "server" runs on a different guest VM (perhaps a Linux server or something)

So the question is:

- How to set up a remote Docker?
- How do you connect to a remote Docker?
- How do you make that as if the remote Docker is running on your local machine, that is, commands work and you can map ports, etc.?

Comment: If nothing else, a remote Docker daemon can't access your "local" files, so it's not going to be that useful for active software development.  It's also tricky to securely set up a remote Docker daemon, and if you get it wrong it's trivial to use it to root the remote host.  I'd avoid this approach.

Comment: Not sure about DFW, but in Linux-land, you just point the docker commands at the remote docker host, eg: `docker -H <remote.IP>:2375 ps`